# error in converting a keras model to coreml format

Tags: ios, deep-learning, keras, coreml, coremltools

converting an h5 file with:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('model.h5')
```

produces the following error:

```
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 722, 
in convert
custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 527, 
in convertToSpec
custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 173, 
in _convert
graph.build()
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_topology2.py", line 714, in 
build
self.make_output_layers()
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_topology2.py", line 174, in 
make_output_layers
self.model.output_layers]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix this ?